# How to add jks file and the jks file password to vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I want to add dev.jks file to vault with the password of jks file.
so when my application tries to use the jks from vault can use the same password to retrieve the cert

Answer (score 1):

So you want to store a file in Vault plus the password for that file ?

You can use a kv value, for example

```
vault kv put secret/dev.jks file="$(dev.jks | base64 -w0)" password=my-pass
```

Comment: why do we have to do base64 and how to retrieve this?

Comment: This doesn't work. It won't load and show null.

Comment: which is the failing part Philip ? Does `dev.jks | base64 -w0` return a valid string ?